# JToken type conversion?

Tags: c#, arrays, json.net

I have a JObject containing parameter/value pairs (e.g. "param1": "aValue"). I want to update these values from data captured in a data grid.

The parameter values are then validated against a JSON schema that defines the following types: "string", "integer" and "array" (of type "string").

My code works fine for as long as the parameter values are of type string. For integers and arrays I get the following error:

```
// parameter validation code
..
IList<string> messages;
bool result = Params.IsValid(paramSchema, out messages);
..
// "Validation error: Invalid type. Expected Integer but got String"
// I get a corresponding error for type "Array"
```

Fair enough, I then added a switch to get the original type so I can cast the new value accordingly:

```
..
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in Param.Rows)
{
    // get current value 
    JToken curToken = aJObject.GetValue(aDatagrid.row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());

    // get new value
    JToken newToken = aDatagrid.row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

    switch (currToken.Type)
    {
        case JTokenType.Integer:
            newToken = convertTokenToInt(newToken); // ==> works but custom method
            break;
        case JTokenType.Array:
            newToken = (JTokenType.Array)newToken; // ==> casting does not work!
            break;
    }

    currToken.Replace(newToken);
}
..
```

With this code I can now handle "strings" and "integers" but I need another custom method for "arrays" (of type "string") or any other type I might use in the future. Not happy with this...

My custom convertTokenToInt(newToken) routine simply assigns the value to an int then reassigns it back to the JToken.

```
.. 
int number;

bool result = int.TryParse(aToken.ToString(), out number);

if (result)
{
    aToken = number;
    return aToken;
}
..
```

This seems to suggest implicit type conversion is possible with JToken's, so why can't I use casting or ConvertTo() or some other more conventional way to map a datagrid cell value to the appropriate JToken type?

Appreciate any help to resolve this simple problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

... here is my conversion method that works, but maybe there is a more elegant solution ...

```
private JToken convertTokenToArray(JToken aToken)
{
    JArray arr = new JArray();            
    List<string> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(aToken.ToString());          

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        JToken i = item;
        arr.Add(i);
    }

    return arr;
}
```